# Magento Saleable quantity not reflecting

Tags: magento2.3, quantity, manage-stock, stock-availability

Here is an interesting one.

All the id numbers were created at the same time but the highlighted ones have both been disabled so should have a '0' for saleable quantity?

The one highlighted at the top does and is not showing on the frontend, but the one at bottom does not so is still showing as available on the frontend.

[image: img]

Any thoughts magento guru's?

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is a matter of scoping of the value set in the status attribute. Click on the disabled product and check the values set in the scope (from upper left corner) All Store Views / Main Website.

My assumption is that your product is disabled in default config scope (all store views) and enabled in Main Website.

Comment: Thanks Diana - not the case on this one but appreciate your feedback. Would this help if I switched to single store mode?

Comment: not really. disabled products should not appear in frontend at all under any circumstance. reindexing all indices and flushing the cache is not working either?

Comment: Thanks Diana - no change with a reindex of flush either. Only way I can get this to reflect is to press the flush magento cache storage which I consider to be a last resort and don't want to be doing these every day to reflect stock. 

is disabling the inventory_msi an option or just a way to patch things over?

Comment: Is there a way to force both scopes to reflect the same stock?

Comment: i still don't seem to be able to see the connection between the product status (enabled/ disabled) and the stock quantity.